# How can I put the second image and the button(bellow it) align?

Tags: html, css, image, button

```css
#services {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(imagens/imagemdefundo1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #efefef !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#services h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #efefef !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#services h1::after {
  content: '';
  background: #efefef;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 420px;
  margin: 20px auto 5px;
}

.image2 img {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto 60px;
  float: right;
}

.image1 img {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
}

.image2 button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  align-items: right;
}

.image1 button {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: -230px;
}
```

```html
<section id="services">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Serviços de entrega</h1>
    <div class="row services">
      <div class="image1">
        <img src="imagens/glovoteste.jpg.png">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Encomendar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="image2">
        <img src="imagens/ubereatstest.jpg.png">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Encomendar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Bootstrap's grid system (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) like the code bellow.

And be careful to use only 1 format on the images `.jpg` or `.png`.

```css
#services {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(imagens/imagemdefundo1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #efefef !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#services h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #efefef !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#services h1::after {
  content: '';
  background: #efefef;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 420px;
  margin: 20px auto 5px;
}

.image2 img {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}

.image1 img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section id="services">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Serviços de entrega</h1>
    <div class="row services">
      <div class="image1 col-6">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/04/14/12/monitor-1307227_1280.jpg">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Encomendar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="image2 col-6">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/04/14/12/monitor-1307227_1280.jpg">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Encomendar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```